# Hazelcast Cache local and distributed cache configuration

Tags: spring-boot, caching, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have configured the Hazelcast cache as distributed in the spring boot application.

```
<group>
    <name>instance1</name>
    <password>pass</password>
</group>

<map name="users">
    <!-- <time-to-live-seconds>30</time-to-live-seconds> -->
    <max-idle-seconds>30</max-idle-seconds>
    <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>
    <max-size policy="PER_NODE">5000</max-size>
    <backup-count>0</backup-count>
    <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
    <read-backup-data>false</read-backup-data>
</map>

<network>
    <port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">5701</port>
    <join>
        <multicast enabled="false">
            <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
            <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
        </multicast>
        <!-- <tcp-ip enabled="false"> <member>127.0.0.1:5709</member> <member>127.0.0.1:5710</member> 
            </tcp-ip> -->
        <tcp-ip enabled="true">
            <interface>127.0.0.1</interface>
        </tcp-ip>
        <aws enabled="false" />
    </join>
</network>

<properties>
    <property name="hazelcast.http.healthcheck.enabled">false</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.health.monitoring.delay.seconds">3000</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.heartbeat.interval.seconds">1500</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.health.monitoring.level">SILENT</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.client.statistics.enabled">false</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.initial.min.cluster.size">0</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.initial.wait.seconds">0</property>
</properties>
```

If I create a group like above and wherever I'm adding this group, that instance cache is in sync.

I want local cache for that same instance where few cache should not be shared.

How to do local and distributed cache together in the application?

Answer (score 0):

@Shakthi, Hazelcast is a distributed in-memory data grid. So every object you created is distributed.

What you can do is to create a second isolated Hazelcast instance in each service so it’ll work like a local cache.

Comment: Hazelcast allows distributed as well as non-distributed as well. If we don't create the group, it will allow local cache.

Comment: @shakthi, if you create a single isolated Hazelcast node on each member, you can achieve what you want. Also edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

@Shakthi - what you are looking for is called NearCache. Take a look at the documentation: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.2/manual/html-single/index.html#near-cache